# Extract urls information from pandas column

Tags: python, pandas, url, tld, urlparse

I need to keep some parts of a link:

```
Link             
www.xxx.co.uk/path1
www.asx_win.com/path2
www.asdfe.aer.com
...
```

Desired output:

```
Link2
xxx.co.uk
asx_win.com
asdfe.aer.com
...
```

I used `urlparse` and `tldextract` but I get either

```
Netloc
www.xxx.co.uk
www.asx_win.com
www.asdfe.aer.com
...
```

or

```
TLDEXTRACT

xxx
asx_win
asdfe.aer
...
```

By using strings, some issues can come from the following:

```
9     https://www.facebook.com/login/?next=https%3A%...
10    https://pt-br.facebook.com/114546123419/pos...
11    https://www.facebook.com/login/?next=https%3A%...
20    http://fsareq.media/?pg=article&id=s...
22    https://www.wq-wq.com/lrq-rqwrq-...
24    https://faseqrq.it/2020/05/28/...
```

My attempt would be to consider differences between what I get from url parse (Netloc) and from tldextract (i.,e., ending part).
For example, from Netloc I get `www.xxx.co.uk` and from tldextract I get `xxx`. This means that if I subtract tldextract from Netloc I get `www` and `co.uk`. I would use as a cut-off point the part in common and keep the part after (i.e., `.co.uk`), that is what I am looking for.

The difference would be given by something like `df['Link2'] = [a.replace(b, '').strip() for a, b in zip(df['Netloc'], df['TLDEXTRACT'])]`. This works only because of the ending part (suffix) that I need to consider.
Now I need to understand how to consider only the ending part to get the expected output. You can use the columns Netloc and TLDEXTRACT in the sample above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tldextract.extract()` returns a named tuple of `(subdomain, domain, suffix)`:

```py
tldextract.extract('www.xxx.co.uk')

# ExtractResult(subdomain='www', domain='xxx', suffix='co.uk')
```

So you can just join indexes `[1:]`:

```py
import tldextract
df['Extracted'] = df.Link.apply(lambda x: '.'.join(tldextract.extract(x)[1:]))

#                                                 Link     Extracted
# 0                                www.xxx.co.uk/path1     xxx.co.uk
# 1                              www.asx_win.com/path2   asx_win.com
# 2                                  www.asdfe.aer.com       aer.com
# 3  https://www.facebook.com/login/?next=https%3A%...  facebook.com
# 4     https://pt-br.facebook.com/114546123419/pos...  facebook.com
# 5  https://www.facebook.com/login/?next=https%3A%...  facebook.com
# 6            http://fsareq.media/?pg=article&id=s...  fsareq.media
# 7                https://www.wq-wq.com/lrq-rqwrq-...     wq-wq.com
# 8                  https://faseqrq.it/2020/05/28/...    faseqrq.it
```

Comment: Thank you so much, tdy! Yes, this is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 2):

First remove http / https:

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse
def remove(row):
    if(row['urls'].str.contains('https') or row['urls'].str.contains('http')):
        return urlparse(row['urls']).netloc
   
withouthttp = df.apply(lambda x: remove(x), axis=1)
```

then :

cut the first 4 signs ("www.")

cut everything after (/)

---

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'urls': ['www.xxx.co.uk/path1', 'www.asx_win.com/path2', 'www.asdfe.aer.com']})
df['urls'] = df['urls'].str[4:]
df['urls'].str.split('/').str[0]
```

---

You can also edit all records with https and http :

```
onlyHttps = df.loc[df['urls'].str.contains("https", case=False)]
allWithoutHttps = df[~df["urls"].str.contains("https", case=False)]
```

and after all operation (removing www and removing http/https - concat proper records)

```
pd.concat([https, http, www])
```

Comment: Ok - cause it's dataframe not series - i'm trying to rework it.

Comment: @LdM - cause there is df['urls'].str[4:] - which cuts first 4 - then h - t - t - p